# Downvoting should be justified

Tags: discussion, feature-request, downvotes

I'm a big fan of the Stack Exchange network and I visit it almost every day - mostly to ask questions on my own or every now and then to answer questions by others.

This Q&A way of communication is superb, but I'd like to address a question about the voting system.
As we all now anybody with such privilege can upvote and/or downvote questions/answers written by others. Now, upvoting is kind of self explanatory: You like the question/answer/comment because it is constructive and useful for the community. As owner of your question/answer/comment you really don't need to know much about the reasons behind the upvote.

Downvoting on the other hand has some negative effects on the owner. Apart from loosing reputation it seems as a negative vote spurs others to vote negative - perhaps even more than upvoting spurs others to upvote. Now, as an owner of a question/answer/comment that receives negative votes it would be encouraging to know the reasons behind negative votes. Of course one could say that "if you really need to know there's always the flag option" but I believe users are more reluctant to flag something they are not sure about how to justify if they have an option to downvote it without justification.

At some point I've been a "victim" of it myself. I received downvotes on an answer that probably wasn't the best to begin with, but as I asked the community for the reasons of downvoting so I could learn from my mistakes, I never received any answer. It seems to me that downvoting *could* be used as a way to hide behind the anonymity that follows the voting system.

I would rather see a system where anyone who downvotes a post must leave a reason for it much like the flag system, but only visible for the owner of the post. To me Stack Exchange is about educating the community by the community and this suggestion could hopefully add to that principle.

What's your thoughts on that matter?

Comment: Quick question: did you research this proposal at all to see if there were similar ones out there?

Comment: "This question/answer doesn't show any research effort: It is unclear or not useful".

Comment: You are yet to meet some _not so friendly users_ who engage in discussions if someone leaves a reason. On receiving a downvote, you can temporarily delete your post and edit to improve the answer, and then undelete it. It stops the flood of downvotes (which I think is your primary concern in the question). Reworking takes time, sometimes a few days if you aren't free at that moment, so save the link to the post if it's an old answer.

Comment: That's a really good advice. I've never thought of it. I also do agree that my question turned out to be a duplicate - a really bad one as such. Did I give it any research effort? Not good enough! I apologize for that.

Answer (score 14):

This is a discussion that comes up every other week or so. Countless times it's been explained that people would just be able to fill in whatever reason they want, and that wouldn't help you at all.

But there's also another thing that I experienced recently. I explained my downvote on an answer (as I do sometimes) and that just turned into an argument between me and the answerer, who thought my downvote was not justified. And the last thing we want is a whole bunch of discussion and anger.

Comment: On top of that, comments filled with the 'bare minimum' would just create a whole bunch of messy noise.

Comment: That's so true. I don't think the reason for down voting should be up for discussion. It would just be so nice to know the reasons behind the down vote. But I see your point and I agree with you. It would be hard to avoid that kind of angered discussions...

Comment: This is what the flag and "contact us" is for. You have the option to report abuse like this. If you choose to engage in it by answering such abuse, you deserve what you get. However, I do have sympathy for the situation as it is not an easy thing to deal with. Me personally - negative or not, I am always thankful for feedback and would not hesitate to flag inappropriate comments and disengage. But while I do feel bad for you - I equally strongly disagree with this as a valid reason. But this is my opinion only.

Comment: If the reason not to have justification because we don't want discussion and anger then the simple remedy is not to allow down-voting at all - and perhaps reduce up-voting to those questions and answers that actually deserve them.

Allowing down voting anonymously doesn't allow the person being down voted to learn from their mistakes if they can't tell who down voted them or if the down voter does not leave a reason.

Down voting is a punishment for those who receive it. Their reputation is damaged. It is used too frequently with impunity - there are better ways than the current system.

Comment: @DaveGordon Yeah, sometimes being on the receiving end of downvotes can feel harsh, especially when you don't have a lot of reputation yet. But you shouldn't take it as punishment, you should take it as an opportunity to improve your own knowledge. Remember that the are imaginary internet points.

Comment: @Stijn You say "you should take it as an opportunity to improve your own knowledge", but the person downvoted is unable to do so because there is no guidance as to what was deficient.  This just happened to me (at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684686/cant-include-state-machine-in-module/37685228#37685228) -- I would love to know what I should have done better but there is no way for me to get an explanation from the voter.

Comment: @KeithBennett Yeah, I don't know anymore what I was trying to convey with that comment, sorry.